# Using a data structure from my C header in assembly file

Tags: c, assembly, struct, nasm

I'm actually learning assembly language (working on Linux) and my question is: I have a C header that contains a linked list like this

```
typedef struct s_list
{
  void *data;
  struct s_list *next;
} t_list;
```

and what I want to do is interact with it in my assembly .s files with functions that I want to use in my C program,
for example in my C program:

```
void *someData = someValue;
t_list *someList = NULL;
someList = listAddBack(somelist, someData);
```

can I include directly my header file in my assembly file or do I have to declare the same struct with `struc` in my assembly file and then do my function from here? Sorry for the bad english by the way i'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly does not have conventions like `struct`, in order to use structs from C you must first know how your C program is laying structs out in memory which may vary wildly between implementations and even compilations due to struct reordering. You will have to manually construct and read your structs in Assembly.

If you simply want to use the structure you laid out in your example however, you are in luck because the C standard dictates that the first item of a struct is always the first in memory and since you only have two items in that struct you can determine where the next item is with certainty.

Assume we are working on x86 and that `edi` is a pointer to your `s_list`

```
mov eax, DWORD [edi] ; eax now holds the data pointer
mov ebx, DWORD [edi + 4] ; 4 bytes is the size of a dword, which in turn is the size of all pointer types in x86, so if we look 4 bytes beyond the pointer to the `s_list` we will find the value for the pointer to next
```

If you want another way of thinking about this, try to look at the code you've written in C and write it without using `struct` anywhere, this will give you an idea of how it works in Assembly.

Comment: Thanks, that answers